# i cannot read the struct value in the dictionary

Tags: c#

i have below struct which i used it in a dictionary but i cannot read its value1 and value2
when i try to read it i get the error : **inaccessible due to its protection level**

```
 public struct Values
    {
        int value1 { get; set; }
        int value2 { get; set; }

        public Values(int value1, int value2)
        {
            if (value1 <= value2)
            {
                this.value1 = value1;
                this.value2 = value2;
            }
            else
            {
                this.value1 = value2;
                this.value2 = value1;
            }
        }
    }
    public static readonly Dictionary< int, Values> dict = new Dictionary<int, Values>
{
    { 0 ,new Values(5, 6) },
    { 1 ,new Values(4, 6)},

};
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (KeyValuePair<int, Values> item in dict.ToList())
        {
            Values tile = item.Value;
            Console.WriteLine("Key: {0}, Value: {1}", item.Key,  tile.value1);

        }

    }
```

Comment: your properties are private properties. make them public

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/accessibility-levels

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change it to this:

```
public int value1 { get; set; }
```

From:

```
int value1 { get; set; }
```

By default, properties are private.

Comment: thanks a lot it works perfectly